# Hover no funciona en button

Tags: css, hover, tailwind

Tengo un boton con el siguiente codigo

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.5.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<button class="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded border-2 border-gray-600 px-4 py-6 rounded-lg transform transition duration-700 hover:scale-110">
  BOTÓN
</button>
```

Estoy usando tailwind y me preguntaba por qué el texto se redimensiona una vez que la transición del botón ha terminado, y no mientras se produce (en la "B" se nota bastante). ¿Qué clases tengo que añadir para que haga el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comportamiento deseado? Lo que veo es un redimensionado normal al pasar el ratón.

Comment: @Juan sería que el texto se vaya redimensionando a medida que cambia el tamaño del botón y no "de golpe"

Comment: Es que yo veo un redimensionamiento gradual del botón, no veo que ocurra de golpe.

Comment: Que raro, yo veo que cuando termina la animación del botón, las letras, en especial la B, da un "golpe" en su tamaño. Quizas ahora con las mayusculas lo veas mejor

Comment: Aora con las mayúsuclas y fijándome mucho parece como si el texto se reposicionara bajando ligeramenre Ino llega a un pixel). Si pongo la escla a 150 no noto ese efecto. De todas formas el efecto es muy sutil.  Y creo que es lo más que puedes conseguir,